# How to filter for rows with NOT NULLS in 2 columns

Tags: sql, filter, null, multiple-columns, aliases

I've been struggling with filtering to display only rows that have do not have NULLS in 2 columns.

- I only want results for clients (rows) who `have a value in both Disability 1 and Disability 2`.
- Do not want to display clients (rows) who `have a value in Disability 1 and NULL in Disability 2 or a NULL in Disability 1 and value in Disability 2`.

My columns are `ClientName, ClientNumber, ClientAge, ClientGender, Disability1, Disability2`

The Disability columns are aliases using CASE.

Issues I've found:

- can't reference aliases in Where or Having clauses, which has made it difficult to filter.
- the Having clause referenced D.DiagnosisName for 2 conditions which means I'm returning no results.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Cheers

My code:

```
SELECT 
    C.ClientName, 
    C.ClientNumber, 
    C.ClientAge, 
    C.ClientGender,
    CASE 
        WHEN    D.DiagnosisName = 'Depression' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Anxiety' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Drug and Alcohol' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Bipolar Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Delusional' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Eating Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Obsessive Compulsive Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Personality Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Post Traumatic Stress Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Post-Natal' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Schizo-affective disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Schizophrenia' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Other Psychiatric/Psychological Disorder' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'BPD' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Psychiatric (other)' 
            THEN D.DiagnosisName 
    END AS [Disability1],
    CASE 
        WHEN    D.DiagnosisName = 'Autism' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Intellectual' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Specific Learning/ADD' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Acquired Brain Injury / Head Injury' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = ' Acquired Brain Injury-Head Injury' 
                OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Neurological' 
        THEN D.DiagnosisName 
    END AS [Disability2]

FROM 
    dbo.FACTClientDiagnosis R
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN DimClient C ON R.DimClientID = C.DimClientID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DimDiagnosisType D ON R.DimDiagnosisTypeID = D.DimDiagnosisTypeID

WHERE 
    ClientStatus = 'Active'     
    AND ClientType = 'Client'
    AND D.DiagnosisName NOT LIKE 'NULL'

GROUP BY 
    C.ClientName, 
    C.ClientNumber, 
    C.ClientAge, 
    C.ClientGender, 
    D.DiagnosisName

HAVING 
    (
        D.DiagnosisName = 'Depression' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Anxiety' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Drug and Alcohol' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Bipolar Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Delusional' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Eating Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Obsessive Compulsive Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Personality Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Post Traumatic Stress Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Post-Natal' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Schizo-affective disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Schizophrenia' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Other Psychiatric/Psychological Disorder' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'BPD' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Psychiatric (other)'
    )
    AND 
    (
        D.DiagnosisName = 'Autism' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Intellectual' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Specific Learning/ADD' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Acquired Brain Injury / Head Injury' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = ' Acquired Brain Injury-Head Injury' 
        OR D.DiagnosisName = 'Neurological'
    ) 

ORDER BY 
    C.ClientName
```

Comment: Just an observation you can replace the multiple OR clauses with an IN statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the derived / aliased columns by wrapping it in another `SELECT .. FROM` as follows. Also, I can't see why you would need `HAVING` in this instance - the filters can be moved to the `WHERE`, as you have no aggregation filters.

```
SELECT ..., x.Disability1, x.Disability2, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT ... AS Disability1,
           ... AS Disability2
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
) AS x
WHERE x.Disability1 IS NOT NULL AND x.Disability2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Some other potential issues

- You can replace the repeated `OR`s with `IN ('Intellectual', 'Autism', ...)`
- You have a filter `(x in (a,b,c))... AND x IN (d,e,f)` - unless there is an overlap, no records will be returned.
- Check for nulls with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` and not `D.DiagnosisName NOT LIKE 'NULL'`